# Compiler error on passing member function to a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, compiler-errors, function-pointers

I am getting a compiler error when I try to pass a member function (from SoundManager class) to a delegate (in EventManager). 
Error:  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Event_Sharp.FunctionHandler' 
Code:

```
public delegate void FunctionHandler(IEvent evnt);
```

EventManager::

```
public void RegisterListener(int type, FunctionHandler handler)
{
    // ...
}
```

SoundManager.cs (constructor):

```
EventManager.Instance.RegisterListener(Event_Bullet_Fired.GetType(), HandleBulletFired );
```

where HandleBulletFired is a member of SoundManager:

```
void HandleBulletFired(Event_Bullet_Fired evnt)
{
    // ...
}
```

and, Event_Bullet_Fired implements IEvent interface. Can someone please tell me why I am getting this error and why I cannot use HandleBulletFired as a delegate ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing is not typesafe, and hence the compiler is complaining.

Think about it like this:

```
interface IAnimal { }
class Lion : IAnimal { public void Roar() {} }
class Giraffe: IAnimal { }
delegate void D(IAnimal animal);
static void M(Lion lion) { lion.Roar(); }
```

Now you say

```
D d = M;
```

Do you see why that doesn't work?  Because nothing is stopping you from saying

```
d(new Giraffe());
```

and now you just made a giraffe roar.  Or, rather, you just crashed the CLR.

To prevent you from doing this, the compiler stops the attempt to make the unsafe assignment.

Note that you *can* go the other way:

```
delegate void D2(Lion lion);
static void M2(IAnimal animal) {}
...
D2 d2 = M2;
```

because now you're going to pass a Lion to d2, which will pass an IAnimal to M2, and Lion is guaranteed to implement IAnimal.

The highfalutin way of saying this is that *method group to delegate conversions are contravariant in their parameter types and covariant in their return types.*

See my series of blog articles on covariance and contravariance for more information.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! I now understand exactly what's going on and why the compiler prevents me from doing this. I was porting some code from C++ to C#, where I was using a base pointer..and well its C++, you can do all sorts of crazy stuff there :)

Comment: @brainydexter: This makes me suspect your C++ code also has an error, but a runtime error instead of a compiler error.

Comment: @Brian: I make sure that I send right event to the function, but its good to know of this potential runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try to cast `HandleBulletFired` to `FunctionHandler`:

```
EventManager.Instance.RegisterListener(Event_Bullet_Fired.GetType(), (FunctionHandler)HandleBulletFired );
```

Comment: On casting, it complains, No overload for HandleBulletFired matches delegate FunctionHandler

Comment: Ok, then maybe to cast Event_Bullet_Fired to IEvent? It seems the compiler is confused, there is (probably) a group method or a method with multiple overloads and method call is ambiguous. Anyway, now you know that HandleBulletFired doesn't match FunctionHandler.

Comment: In previous comment I mean that there is a group of methods HandleBulletFired and compiler cannot resolve which of them is appropriate - so you have to cast either HandleBulletFired to FunctionHandler or Event_Bullet_Fired to IEvent or both of them.

Comment: I just have one function with that name, but yes, changing the signature as mentioned by Andrew (see above), did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this `Event_Bullet_Fired.GetType()` returns int as `RegisterListener` method requires:

```
public void RegisterListener(int type, FunctionHandler handler)
```

**Updated**:

I think that the reason of error is that `Event_Bullet_Fired` is more specific that `IEvent`.
Try substitute `Event_Bullet_Fired` to `IEvent` in the `HandleBulletFired` method declaration:

```
void HandleBulletFired(IEvent evt)
{
    Event_Bullet_Fired bullerFiredEvent = (Event_Bullet_Fired)evt;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: 'GetType()' is implemented for Event_Bullet_Fired. Also, I replaced it by 1, and I still get the same error

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it, but what concerns me is this. Event_Bullet_Fired implements interface IEvent, so why does it complain at compile-time ?